# Get material from assets

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In my Unity Project I try to highlight some object with some self-made material.
Unfortunately the codes I found does not work.

The following script is added to three different GameObjects:

```
Renderer[] rend_ThisObject;
Material white, red;

void Start()
{
    // I tried the following two code parts:
    white = Resources.Load<Material>("White");
    white = Resources.Load("Material/White.mat", typeof(Material)) as Material;

    red = Resources.Load<Material>("Red");
    red = Resources.Load("Material/Red.mat", typeof(Material)) as Material;           
}

void Update()
{
    foreach (var child in rend_ThisObject)
    {
        child.material = blinkObject ? white : red;
    }
}
```

If I run the project the game objects with the script appears in pink and do not blink.

If I change the `Material white, red;` to `public Material white, red;` it works fine. What do I have to change to get the materials from my assets/resources/material folder?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In general:

From Unity's own [Best practise for `Resources`](https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/assets-resources-and-assetbundles#5c7f8528edbc2a002053b5a7):

> **Don't use it.**

What was wrong with simply using your `public` fields and set them via the Inspector?

If you don't like them to be `public` then simply use [`[SerializeField]`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SerializeField.html)

```
[SerializeField] private Material white;
[SerializeField] private Material red;
```

instead and assign them via the Inspector!

---

Then assuming your path is not `assets/resources/material` but rather `Assets/Resources/Material` see [`Resources.Load`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.Load.html)!

You tried

```
white = Resources.Load<Material>("White");
white = Resources.Load("Material/White.mat", typeof(Material)) as Material;
```

**Both are wrong:**

- The first time it is missing the folder path

  > The path is relative to any folder named `Resources` inside the `Assets` folder of your project
- the second has the file ending too much.

  > **Note**: Extensions must be omitted.

So for loading the file with path

```
Assets/Resources/Material/White.mat
```

it should simply be

```
white = Resources.Load<Material>("Material/White");
```

---

Now another general note:

Doing this blink on a **per frame** basis is not a god idea!

Rather use some sort of delay like e.g.

```
// adjust via the Inspector as well
[Tooltip("Color changes per second")]
[SerializeField] private float blinkFrequency = 2f;

private float timer;

void Update()
{
    timer -= Time.deltaTime;
    if(timer <= 0)
    {
        timer = 1 / blinkFrequency;

        blinkObject = !blinkObject;
        foreach (var child in rend_ThisObject)
        {
            child.material = blinkObject ? white : red;
        }
    }
}
```